# Firebase facebook signInWithRedirect not redirecting to specified page on login success

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am using Firebase's facebook signInWithRedirect but can't figure out why my application won't navigate to the specific page on redirect and instead it just returns back to the home page. I followed the steps on https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/facebook-login and believe I have setup everything correctly. Below is my login code:

```js
$("#login").click(function() {
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);
    }
  });

firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
      if (result.credential) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        var user_data = result.user.providerData[0];
        currentUid = user_data.uid;
    
        var usersRef = firebase.database().ref().child('users');
        usersRef.child(currentUid).once('value', function(snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.val() !== null && snapshot.val().Phone !== undefined) {
            localStorage.setItem("UID", currentUid);
            localStorage.setItem("Name", user_data.displayName);
            window.location = "/zones"; //Navigate to this route
          } else {

          var userDataJson = {
            "Name": user_data.displayName,
            "Email": user_data.email,
            "Phone": user_data.phoneNumber
          };

          var childRef = usersRef.child(currentUid)
          childRef.set(userDataJson).then(snap => {
            localStorage.setItem("UID", currentUid);
            localStorage.setItem("Name", user_data.displayName);
            window.location = "/profile" ; //or Navigate to this route
            });
          }
        });
      }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage);
        var email = error.email;
        var credential = error.credential;;
        });
```

In Firebase console I have the following domains listed in Authorized Domains:
1. localhost
2. my firebase oauth domain
3. my site domain that I'll be hosting the app on

In the Facebook dev console I have listed the following in Valid OAuth redirect URIs:
1.https://myblahblah.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
2.https://mydomain/profile
3.https://mydomain/zones

What am I doing wrong here, been trying to figure this out for hours!!

Comment: Your code looks incorrect. You are calling `firebase.auth().getRedirectResult()` in the same login callback. That should be handled externally to check if the user is returning back from a redirect sign-in. `signInWithRedirect` will always redirect you back to the same back where it was called with the user signed in.

Comment: wait so how should the layout be? on click I should be calling     firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);? and then firebase.auth().getRedirectResult() should be called outside of that onclick function?

Comment: Updated my question with the right format..still facing the issue where after fb login, I get stuck back on my login page from where the fb login was initiated. However, after a few seconds my page does navigate to the correct route but it still brings me back to the login page right after login...

Comment: That is expected. `signInWithRedirect` will bring you back to the same login page. You detect the user is signed in and redirect to the user page. You can also use `onAuthStateChanged` to detect when a user is already signed in and redirect with that, however, you can't get the OAuth credential from there.

Comment: how do I redirect user to a new specific page immediately after login? How can I specify the page

Comment: I already explained twice that this works as intended. After you redirect back to the same page and sign in is completed, you simply redirect on your own to the signed in page: `window.location.assign('/signedIn');`

Comment: is there no way for me to basically do this: login_page => fb auth login => new page

vs this what is currently happening: login_page =>fb auth login => login_page => new page

Comment: There is no way to do that.